# Postgres SQL: How to select the highest value in the "media" column for the same time stamp in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I am using possql through the DataGrip program. I have the following table:

```
    timestamp       | Channel |  media
-----------------------------------------
2020-04-29 00:00:00 |   3     |   1.2
2020-04-29 00:00:00 |   4     |    2
2020-04-29 00:00:00 |   5     |    1
2020-04-29 00:10:00 |   3     |    2
2020-04-29 00:10:00 |   4     |   1.5
2020-04-29 00:10:00 |   5     |    3
```

I would like to sort by the highest value in the "media" column for each "timestamp", as follows:

```
    timestamp       | Channel |  media
-----------------------------------------
2020-04-29 00:00:00 |   4     |    2
2020-04-29 00:10:00 |   5     |    3
```

How can I do this?

I tried to do this but it didn't work, it's repeating the original table:

```
SELECT timestamp, max(media), channel
FROM monitoring_aggregate
GROUP BY timestamp, channel
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, just can just use `distinct on` to solve this top-1-per-group problem:

```
select distinct on (timestamp) ma.*
from monitoring_aggregate ma
order by timestamp, media desc
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! And if you have 4 columns, to choose only 3 and do the same sorting, as I would do?